# Printing to the console in the Try-Catch with Resources

Tags: java, try-catch

I want the server to print to the console when a player connects via sockets. However, my IDE barks at me for trying to use System.out.println("P1 Connected") inside the try-catch with resources.

I looked into the issue and found that the calls inside the try-catch with resources must implement closeable. While this does make sense these are blocking calls and I cant seem to find another way to assure I print immediately after a player connects.

I could break it up into two try-catch w/ resources however I lose the reference to the client sockets for P1 and P2. As far as I am aware all my operations on these sockets must happen within the {} following the try-catch because otherwise they are closed and due to the scope they can no longer be accessed.

```
//Setup the server socket for client one
        try (

                ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(Integer.parseInt(args[1]));
                Socket clientOne = serverSocket.accept();
                BufferedReader clientOneIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientOne.getInputStream()));
                PrintWriter clientOneOut = new PrintWriter(clientOne.getOutputStream(), true);
                System.out.println("Player one connected!");

                Socket clientTwo = serverSocket.accept();
                BufferedReader clientTwoIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientTwo.getInputStream()));
                PrintWriter clientTwoOut = new PrintWriter(clientTwo.getOutputStream(), true);
        ) {

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: you can nest to try block

Comment: I decided on just using a try without references and manually closing everything. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

I used the Constructor of a Closeable class:

```
import java.io.Closeable;
class CloseableLogger implements Closeable {
    CloseableLogger(String message) {
        System.out.println(message);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        // Do nothing
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
try (
    CloseableLogger c1 = new CloseableLogger("Before creating Buffered Reader");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
    CloseableLogger c2 = new CloseableLogger("After creating Buffered Reader");
) {
    // Code
}
```